# Instantiating and destroying unity prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a platformer in unity and have a platform that randomly generates. I am able to get the platform object to spawn but cannot get it to be destroyed.

Any help on creating / destroying prefabs would be highly appreciated.

```
public GameObject platform;
private Vector2 screenBounds;

void Start()
{    // Spawn the platforms
    Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2();
    for ( int i=0; i < platformCount; i++) 
    {
        spawnPosition.y = Random.Range(1f , 10f);
        spawnPosition.x = Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f);
        instance = Instantiate(platform, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (instance != null) 
    {
        if (platform.transform.position.y < screenBounds.y * 5) 
        {
            Destroy(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `instance` is being reassigned for each instantiated object, so `instance` in FixedUpdate refers only to the last instantiated object. It's also not great practice for the object doing the instantiating to also be responsible for destroying objects. A better solution would be to create a script (named for example: "DestroyWhenOffscreen.cs") to attach to the prefabs that handles the destruction logic.

Comment: I will recommend to check out about the 'object-pooling' design patern which is best practise of what you are trying to achieve here. When you Instantiate an object it can be performance heavy, depends on the object and also when you destroy the object is not fully destroyed or removed from the memory and to avoid any possible future performance issues you can migrate to 'object-pooling', where you instantiate an amount of objects at the start of the game and simply enable them when you need them and disable/reset them instead of destroying them

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was already mentioned in the comments:

```
instance = Instantiate(platform, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

this is re-assigned in a loop so it will only end up with the very last iteration's instance.

Further in your check you are using the original prefab

```
if (platform.transform.position.y < screenBounds.y * 5)
```

this is the **prefab** from the assets you instantiate so of course it never moves in the scene at all.

---

I would either split this into its very own script and do e.g.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerialzieField] private OffScreenDestroy platformPrefab;

    void Start()
    {  
        for ( int i=0; i < platformCount; i++) 
        {
            var spawnPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(1f , 10f), Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f));
            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }  
    }
}
```

and

```
// Attach this to your platform prefab
public class OffScreenDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2? screenBounds;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(screenBounds == null) screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        if(transform.position.y < screenBounds.Value.y * 5) 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively keep them in a collection and do e.g.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject platformPrefab;

    private readonly List<GameObject> instances = new();
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    private void Start()
    {  
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        for ( int i=0; i < platformCount; i++) 
        {
            var spawnPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(1f , 10f), Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f));
            instances.Add(Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity));
        }  
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for(var i = instances.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var instance = instances[i];
            if(instance.tranform.position.y < screenBounds.Value.y * 5) 
            {
                Destroy(instance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```